# How to use Select2 with JSON via Ajax request?

Tags: javascript, json, laravel, jquery-select2

My [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) 3.4.5 is not working with JSON data.

Here is my input box on HTML:

```
<input class='form-control col-lg-5 itemSearch' type='text' placeholder='select item' />
```

…and my JavaScript

```
$(".itemSearch").select2({
    placeholder: "Search for an Item",
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    ajax: {
        url: "/api/productSearch",
        dataType: 'json',
        quietMillis: 100,
        data: function (term, page) {
            return {
                option: term
            };
        },
        results: function (data, page) {
            var more = (page * 10) < data.total;
            return {
                results: data.itemName,
                more: more
            };
        }
    },
    formatResult: function (data, term) {
        return data;
    },
    formatSelection: function (data) {
        return data;
    },
    dropdownCssClass: "bigdrop",
    escapeMarkup: function (m) {
        return m;
    }
});
```

I made an API with Laravel 4 which returns a value whenever I type anything on my text box.

Here's the result if I type "test" on my text box:

```
[{"itemName":"Test item no. 1","id":5},
{"itemName":"Test item no. 2","id":6},
{"itemName":"Test item no. 3","id":7},
{"itemName":"Test item no. 4","id":8},
{"itemName":"Test item no. 5","id":9},
{"itemName":"Test item no. 6","id":10},
{"itemName":"Test item no. 7","id":11}]
```

I can't add the result to my Select2 dropdown. I think `formatSelection` and `formatResult` are causing the problem because I don't know what parameter should be placed on it. I don't know where to get those parameters like container, object and query and the values it should be returning, or is my JSON response is wrong?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Here you have an example

```
$("#profiles-thread").select2({
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    tags: [],
    ajax: {
        url: URL,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "GET",
        quietMillis: 50,
        data: function (term) {
            return {
                term: term
            };
        },
        results: function (data) {
            return {
                results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                    return {
                        text: item.completeName,
                        slug: item.slug,
                        id: item.id
                    }
                })
            };
        }
    }
});
```

It's quite easy

Comment: Can you explain the "slug" parameter?

Comment: item is object with completeName, slug and id properties. This is just an example, copy and paste.

Comment: From where you take "slug" param -?
i can find only: itemName & id

Comment: Slug it is an actual property of item, your item, I added this as you can see how to add extra parameters ;)

Comment: I recive this error jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null when my server return no result.

Comment: It works for a single select box, but if I include two select boxes on the same page, only the last one loads. Is it normal behavior?

Comment: @Khalilullah is because the id of element is targeted (`#profiles-thread`) - and ids are unique in HTML document. You should probably target some css class etc,

Answer (score 126):

for **select2 v4.0.0** slightly different

```
$(".itemSearch").select2({
    tags: true,
    multiple: true,
    tokenSeparators: [',', ' '],
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    minimumResultsForSearch: 10,
    ajax: {
        url: URL,
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        data: function (params) {

            var queryParameters = {
                term: params.term
            }
            return queryParameters;
        },
        processResults: function (data) {
            return {
                results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                    return {
                        text: item.tag_value,
                        id: item.tag_id
                    }
                })
            };
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Can't get this to work... :( No calls being made to server.

Comment: It worked thanks, the mistake i made was not mapping properly to `id` and `text` key values.

Answer (score 24):

Here I give you my example which contain --> **Country flag, City, State, Country.**

Here is my output.

[image]

Attach these two Cdn js or links.

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

**js script**

```
//for apend flag of country.

function formatState (state) {
    console.log(state);
    if (!state.id) {
      return state.text;
    }
    var baseUrl = "admin/images/flags";
    var $state = $(
      '<span><img src="'+baseUrl+ '/' + state.contryflage.toLowerCase() + '.png"  class="img-flag" /> ' +state.text+ '</span>'
    );
    return $state;
  };


$(function(){
    $("#itemSearch").select2({
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    templateResult: formatState, //this is for append country flag.
    ajax: {
        url: URL,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "POST",
        data: function (term) {
            return {
                term: term
            };
        },
        processResults: function (data) {
            return {
                results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                    return {
                        text: item.name+', '+item.state.name+', '+item.state.coutry.name,
                        id: item.id,
                        contryflage:item.state.coutry.sortname
                    }
                })
            };
        }

    }
});
```

**Expected JSON response.**

```
[
   {
      "id":7570,
      "name":"Brussels",
      "state":{
         "name":"Brabant",
         "coutry":{
            "sortname":"BE",
            "name":"Belgium",

         }
      }
   },
   {
      "id":7575,
      "name":"Brussels",
      "state":{
         "name":"Brabant Wallon",
         "coutry":{
            "sortname":"BE",
            "name":"Belgium",

         }
      }
   },
   {
      "id":7578,
      "name":"Brussel",
      "state":{
         "name":"Brussel",
         "coutry":{
            "sortname":"BE",
            "name":"Belgium",

         }
      }
   },

]
```

Comment: but i m confusing in `        data: function (term) {
            return {
                term: term
            };
        },`

Answer (score 21):

In Version 4.0.2 slightly different Just in `processResults` and in `result` :

```
    processResults: function (data) {
        return {
            results: $.map(data.items, function (item) {
                return {
                    text: item.tag_value,
                    id: item.tag_id
                }
            })
        };
    }
```

You must add `data.items` in `result`. `items` is Json name :

```
{
  "items": [
    {"id": 1,"name": "Tetris","full_name": "s9xie/hed"},
    {"id": 2,"name": "Tetrisf","full_name": "s9xie/hed"}
  ]
}
```

Comment: If i remove `items` from `data.items` i wouldn't need to add `items` attribute on the response right ? ;)

Comment: @bekicot yes, you just only specify `$.map(data, function (item)` 
if your json is an array: `[ {"id": 1,"text": "One"}, {"id": 2,"text": "Two"} ]`

Comment: Have been bashing my head against a wall and this cleared things up. Thank you, the documentation for select2 is severely lacking.

Answer (score 11):

This is how I fixed my issue, I am getting data in data variable and by using above solutions I was getting error `could not load results`. I had to parse the results differently in processResults.

```
searchBar.select2({
            ajax: {
                url: "/search/live/results/",
                dataType: 'json',
                headers : {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
                delay: 250,
                type: 'GET',
                data: function (params) {
                    return {
                        q: params.term, // search term
                    };
                },
                processResults: function (data) {
                    var arr = []
                    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                        arr.push({
                            id: index,
                            text: value
                        })
                    })
                    return {
                        results: arr
                    };
                },
                cache: true
            },
            escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; },
            minimumInputLength: 1
        });
```

Answer (score 4):

My ajax never gets fired until I wrapped the whole thing in

`setTimeout(function(){ .... }, 3000);`

I was using it in mounted section of Vue. it needs more time.

Answer (score 2):

Tthe problems may be caused by incorrect mapping. Are you sure you have your result set in "data"? In my example, the backend code returns results under "items" key, so the mapping should look like:

```
results: $.map(data.items, function (item) {
....
}
```

and not:

```
 results: $.map(data, function (item) {
    ....
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If ajax request is not fired, please check the select2 class in the select element. Removing the select2 class will fix that issue.