# populate select2 from ajax every keyup

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I'm not very familiar with [`select2.js`](https://select2.github.io/) and the documentation is not that easy to understand.

I have a Compose Message module and I have a `select2` with tagging support as the input for the recipient of the message. Every keyup will fire an ajax which will query all the results `WHERE something LIKE '%something%'`.

The result of the ajax is something like this (when there is already 1 result):

```
[{
    id : 12102719,
    firstname : "John",
    lastname : "Doe"
}]
```

What it will supposed to look like if displayed normally

```
echo "<option value='".$sendTo['id']."'>".$sendTo['firstname']." ".$sendTo['lastname']."</option>";
```

My HTML is something like this:

```
<select multiple="true" name="tagRecipients[]" id="tagRecipients" class="form-control select2 input-inline input-xlarge"></select>
```

My CI Controller looks like this

```
public function sendToUser() {
    $findthis = $this->input->post('findthis');
    $this->data['recipients'] = $this->User_model->sendToUser($findthis);
    if($this->data['recipients']){
        foreach($this->data['recipients'] as $sendTo){
            echo "<li id='select2-tagRecipients-result-".$sendTo['school_id']."' class='select2-results__option' role='treeitem' aria-selected='false'>".$sendTo['firstname']." ".$sendTo['lastname']."</li>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "No match found";
    }
}
```

My script looks like this

```
$(document).on('keyup','.select2-search__field',function(){
    $('.select2-results__option').remove();
    var tosearch = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: BASE_URL+'users/sendtouser',
        data: {findthis: tosearch},
        success: function(data){
            $('#select2-tagRecipients-results').append(data);
        }
    });       
});
```

The problem is that the results appended by the ajax can't be clicked.

I believe it is because I just manually accessed the elements created by the theme. The classes and ids `.select2-results__option`, `#select2-tagRecipients-results`, `.select2-search__field` are all from just inspecting the elements using FireBug. Including the whole `echo` line in the controller.

Basically, what is supposed to happen is that the user can type in some keywords and the results with `WHERE column_value LIKE '%keywords%'` will be shown as options. And then multiple results can be selected as recipients.

Comment: Try to read the [`ajax` examples](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-ajax) and [`ajax` options](https://select2.github.io/options.html#ajax) Keep attention to return the structure the plugin need.

Comment: So I should call `$(".js-data-example-ajax").select2({` `on('keyup')`? Should I keep the `.select2-search__field` as the selector (it is dynamically created)?

Comment: No!! the `ajax` option do it by himself. You can set the `delay` of the `keypress` and more but let the plugin to do the job because he doing this better.. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20926707/how-to-use-select2-with-json-via-ajax-request) maybe it can help you..

Comment: How should my `Controller` look like? My HTML and script now looks like this https://jsfiddle.net/iamdevlin/92qo96c7/

Comment: Of course.. your controller need to return a `json` but not an `html` content. Your `json` need to look like in the question I posted. Something like: `[{"itemName":"Test item no. 1","id":5}]`. I found a [tutorial](http://www.southcoastweb.co.uk/jquery-select2-v4-ajaxphp-tutorial) of `select2` and `php`. Let me know if you OK with it.

Comment: Works great now. I just added `multiple` to the `<select />` and now it supports multiple recipients. Thank you for the link.