# Select2 input field not being populated when dynamically added option is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I am successfully populating a select2 (v4.0.1) dropdown with dynamically (via AJAX) retrieved options.

Here is the HTML:

```
<select id="part-reference" class="select-dropdown" name="part-reference"></select>
```

Here is the Javascript:

```
$('#part-reference').select2({
        ajax: {
            url: function (params) {
                return "parts/parts-search?nodecorator=true&input=" + params.term;
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            type: "POST",
            delay: 300,
            processResults: function (data, params) {
                return {
                    results: data.results
                };
            },
            cache: true
        }
    });
```

The AJAX response looks like this:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "text": "Two"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "text": "Three"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I select one of the options in the dropdown the input field is not populated with the text, and when I submit the form the value for this select is `undefined`.

What do I need to do so that when a dynamically added option is clicked, it populates the input field and sets its value?

Comment: Could you please make a jsfiddle so that other people quickly check and help?

Comment: use `$.map` check this example [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20926707/how-to-use-select2-with-json-via-ajax-request)

Comment: Should I need to use `$.map`? I think my data is in the correct format?

Comment: You're right you don't need to use a `map` as the format is correct. It seems to work fine: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2104/4uzap0Lx/6/) Try using the `targetSelection` option to force print the value (either ID or text)