# How to preloaded select2 plugin with AJAX?

Tags: jquery-select2

In this example: https://jsfiddle.net/wqd4ebyn/2/:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-example-basic-single').select2(
      {
          ajax: {
          url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos',
          dataType: 'json'
          }
      }
    );
});
```

I am trying to fetch remote data with ajax and preload the list with the current options. It does not work unless I have removed the ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-example-basic-single').select2(
    );
});
```

My list is so big. What I want is to list some options that is so common and the rest by ajax. The current implementation does allow to do both, either static option or dynamic. I need both.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look on the official documentation: https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax
You need to have a function which will handle the Request parameters and another function which handles the Response data.

Have you tried this? 
[How to use Select2 with JSON via Ajax request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20926707/how-to-use-select2-with-json-via-ajax-request)

**EDIT:**
I created here a JSFIddle with your code: https://jsfiddle.net/7bdeo38c/6/

HTML:

```
<select class="js-example-basic-single" name="state"></select>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-example-basic-single').select2(
      {
        ajax: {
          url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: function (params) {
            return {
              q: params.term // search term
            };
          },
          processResults: function (data) {
            return {
              results: data // results
            };
          }
        },
        templateResult: formatResults, // Controls how the dropdown looks
        templateSelection: formatSelection, // Controls what is displayed after selecting an item
        escapeMarkup: function (m) { return m; }, // Let our custom formatter work
      }
    );
});

function formatResults (data) {
  if (data.loading) {
    return data.text;
  }

  var result;
  if (data.completed) {
        result = "<div class='select2-result-repository__description'>" + data.title + "</div>";
  }
  return result;
}

function formatSelection (data) {
  return data.id + ' - ' + data.title || data.text;
}
```

A similar example exists in the official Select2 documentation. See the end of the Ajax chapter for the full code of the GitHub repositories example.
https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax

Comment: I have tried every this without any luck. Can you give me an example please? Thanks anyway.

Comment: Check my answer again please

Comment: Sorry, Maybe I was not clear in my question. My list is so big. What I want is to list some options that so common and the rest by ajax. The current implementation does allow to do both, either static option or dynamic. I need both. Thank for your help.

Comment: Ah, ok, Sorry, I understood something else. I think you might need a Custom Data Adapter for that, although not sure how that would be implemented.